# Convert a 2d array of strings to a 2d array of double swift

Tags: arrays, swift, string, type-conversion, double

I have 2 arrays:

```
var locationString = [[String]]()
var doubleArray = [[Double]]()
```

The array data is appended after a parser has ran just in case you are wondering why there is no data.

Essentially I am trying to convert the **locationString** from string to double.
I originally tried the following:

```
let doubleArray = locationString.map{ Double($0) }
```

but this does not seem to work as i get an error of:

```
Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Double' with an argument list of type ((String]))
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `let doubleArray = locationString.map{$0.compactMap(Double.init)}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `map` with `compactMap` map:

```
let doubleArray = locationString.map { $0.compactMap(Double.init) }
```

**Example:**

```
let locationString = [["1.2", "2.3"], ["3.4", "4.4", "hello"]]

let doubleArray = locationString.map { $0.compactMap(Double.init) }

print(doubleArray) // [[1.2, 2.3], [3.4, 4.4]]
```

The outer `map` processes each array of strings.  The inner `compactMap` converts the `String`s to `Double` and drops them if the conversion returns `nil` because the `String` is not a valid `Double`.

---

To trim leading and trailing whitespace in your `String`s before converting to `Double`, use `.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)`:

```
let doubleArray = locationString.map { $0.compactMap { Double($0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces )) } }
```

Comment: This seems correct, although for some reason when I try and print the data, the output is just `[[], [], [], [], []]` have any ideas as to why it is doing this?

Comment: Check your input.  The `String`s cannot have leading or trailing spaces.  You could trim those as well if needed.

Comment: Yeah, I've just noticed something when printing the `locationString` after the data is appended. The data is not being separated by the comma which it should be, so for example the first element looks like this: `[["55.949636-3.19108]]` I believe this is most likely the cause, do you have any help to separate the data with a comma when it is appended?

Comment: What does the original input look like?

Comment: So the original input is pulled from some XML data, it is being pulled as a string (definitely my bad but at this point its easier to work around than change original code). The data is appended to the array with the following: `locationString.append([myTrail.trailLatitude + myTrail.trailLongitude])` when you print the data of the `locationString` array it looks like this: `[["55.949636-3.19108]]`

Comment: I would think you'd want `locationString.append([myTrail.trailLatitude,  myTrail.trailLongitude])`. That `+` is concatenating your strings.  Also, I don't know where that leading `"` is coming from, but you'll need to get rid of that too.

Comment: haha jesus I'm an idiot, thanks for that, I had the + originally as I was working with a 1 dimensional array. Thanks for the help man, its working now, appreciate it